# Bootstrap: different colors of different columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I have something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to have a different backgrounds for the different sizes like so:

```
.col-xs-12 {
background-color: blue;
}

.col-md-9 {
background-color: yellow;
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use css media queries.

This is the breakpoints used by bootstrap 3--

[image]

So your media queries should look like the below snippet--

```css
.column1 {
background-color: yellow;
height:200px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) { 
.column1 {
background-color: red;
}
}

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: 992px) { 
.column1 {
background-color: blue;
}
}

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: 1200px) { 
.column1 {
background-color: green;
}}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        

<div class="container">
  <div id="row">
    <div class="column1 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9"></div>
    <div class="column2 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add an extra class and add media queries on them, like so:

```css
.color-class { /* for col-xs-12 */
  background-color: blue;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) { /* for col-sm-12 */
  .color-class {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}
 col-lg-9 color-class
@media (min-width: 992px) { /* for col-md-9*/
  .color-class {
    background-color: red;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) { /* for col-lg-9*/
  .color-class {
    background-color: grey;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div id="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9 color-class">sample text</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9 color-class">sample text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Media Queries** would be the solution you are looking for -

We can have different blocks of CSS code for different screen and device sizes. In today's world, users view web pages on a wide range of screens. Screens can range from the large displays on their work stations, to their laptops on the air plane, to their iPad or other tablets while sitting in the park and finally on their small mobile phone screens on the go.

If your browser supports media queries, then you're good to go.

**Different Styles for Different Screens: How it Works**

You must be thinking that to achieve this, you will have to learn a whole new chapter of CSS. Fortunately you don't have to. All it takes is a few extra lines of code, or sometimes just a few words. The simplest way to use media queries is to have a block of CSS code in the same stylesheet file. So all the CSS that is specific to mobile phones, would be defined in the following block:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
/* define mobile specific styles come here */
}
```

Usually we would define this at the end of the file in order to leverage the cascading property of CSS. The background color, the borders and other common attributes would typically be defined above and wont be changed here. The following properties are the ones that we would replace most often:

- height
- width
- float
- margins

For example, let's say the logo of the company is 600 pixel wide on the desktop version of the website. Now on a device with a width of 480 pixels, the scroller will appear and that is not desirable. So we should have a smaller version of the logo and the CSS file would look like this:

```
#logo { background: url(images/logo.png); width: 600px; border: 1px #ccc solid; }
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
#logo { background: url(images/logo_mobile.png); width: 440px; }
}
```

If you notice, we have not over-written the border property for the logo, so the border will continue to show on mobile devices.